# site:mysite.com shows home page as HTTPS, home page not showing in search properly

Tags: search-engines, https

site: rockitpro.com

I've been trying to figure out a problem with my site since August 2012, my home page fell off the map and won't show in Google unless I search exactly **rockitpro.com**. My home page doesn't show for my website's name **rockitpro** or any of my targeted keywords. If you search my main keyword **buy beats** my site is on page 2 but it points to a category page. I figured it was Panda/Penguin but after cleaning up my site and contacting Google, they said that no manual action had ever been taken.

I just did a **site:rockitpro.com** and the first result shows HTTPS : //www.rockitpro.com/

In Bing searching for **buy beats rockitpro** shows https but searching for **rockitpro** shows the normal http.

I checked my domain in Plesk and it has no SSL certificates, I've never enabled ssl security on my website. Searching site:rockitpro.com inurl:https -inurl:http shows a few weird links.

Searched Google and found 18 sites that link to my site via https. How do I fix this and do you guys think this is the problem as to why my home page isn't showing up in search correctly or is it a deeper problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve this problem by using [Rel Canonical](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) on your pages.

**HTML** In the `<head> </head>` of ***EACH PAGE*** use the following:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/url-here"/>
```

By using canonical you are telling Google the master page therefor pages on the HTTPS will not be indexed and not be duplicates either. There are many SEO plugins that will do this for you.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the canonical tag for all posts, pages, etc. in my Wordpress site. I used conditional tags in the header.php.

Should I ask Google to deindex the https:// version or will that remove the http:// home page as well? Or should I just wait and let Google do it's thing now that I have canonical tags?

Comment: Don't tell Google to deindex them as you could drop traffic and even rankings if the page doesn't return as it was... Just be patient and Google will correct the problem over time.

Comment: The important thing is that Visitors can still find your site, removing them means you need Google to reindex you which can lose in rankings as well as take donkeys to index all pages. GJ on adding it :P